# How to add tap gesture on button inside UItableCell in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have made a custom cell.In each custom cell there are many button like 3 to 4 i want add tap gesture for each button inside that cell.So that i can uniquely identify which cell's button was clicked.I have searched a lot but didn't find any good solution.

Please tell.

Comment: you dont need tap gesture for that. What you need is a button action method that recognises the action event by either tag or either by title

Comment: but i have so many buttons for diffrent cells how can i identify which button is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to access the `button` you can directly access, no need of Gesture

do like

```
[yourButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(selectButtonPressed1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
yourButton1.tag=indexPath.row;

 [yourButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(selectButtonPressed2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
yourButton2.tag=indexPath.row;

 [yourButton3 addTarget:self action:@selector(selectButtonPressed3:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
yourButton3.tag=indexPath.row;


 [yourButton4 addTarget:self action:@selector(selectButtonPressed4:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
yourButton4.tag=indexPath.row;
```

**Method - 1**

```
-(void)selectButtonPressed1:(UIButton*)sender
{
NSLog(@"selcted button1");
}
```

**Method - 2**

```
-(void)selectButtonPressed2:(UIButton*)sender
{
NSLog(@"selcted button2");
}
```

**Method - 3**

```
-(void)selectButtonPressed3:(UIButton*)sender
{
NSLog(@"selcted button3");
}
```

**Method - 4**

```
-(void)selectButtonPressed4:(UIButton*)sender
{
NSLog(@"selcted button4");
}
```

Comment: How can i identify which cell button was clicked

Comment: it is identify with tags means **yourButton4.tag=indexPath.row;** , it is identify which cell you clicked on tableview

Comment: @deepak - any doubt about this

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have n number of buttons. And you have one butotn action method:

YOu need to connect this method to all of your n buttons (touch up inside), so that whenever you press a button, this method will get hit.

You can either give tag values for your buttons or you can recognise them by thier title

```
-(IBAction) nButtonActions:(id)sender{

         if([[sender titleLabel] isEqualtoString:@"your button-1 title"]){
                 //call your method for button -1
           }

     //or you can do the same using sender.tag


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use restoration identifier.

```
button.restorationIdentifier = @"Cell Number _ button tag";
```

for example

```
button.restorationIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", indexPath.row];

NSString* rowIndexStr = ((UIButton*)sender).restorationIdentifier;
```